# How to determine if transformer has air gap or not

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter

I got a transformer out of a broken electronics circuit. I don't know what the circuit was, however I know the transformer was used in some sort of isolated DC-DC converter, as it was right next to a bunch of capacitors and IGBT modules. I would like to use the transformer in my own DC-DC converter.

**My question is this**: How can I measure if this transformer has a air gap (aka should be used in a fly back converter) or doesn't (and should be used in a forward converter?) without cutting it open?

I have access to an LCR meter, oscilloscope, function generator, and power supply. There are no useful markings on the outside of the transformer.

[Here are pictures](https://photos.app.goo.gl/5H6uHTdXsitks6x58) if I am just too stupid to look in the right spot.

As far as I can tell the text reads EE55-HZ 1.07 15.40.5 and all I could get from that was [this link](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32225412892.html). It doesn't look like it has an air gap.

Comment: As an ancillary issue, do you know or can you identify, from the broken electronics circuit, which winding(s) are the primaries, secondaries, and aux(es)?  There is little hope of going further without knowing which pins are for what.  Because measuring it blindly might lead you to believe a winding is for one purpose (primary), when actually it is for something else (aux.)  You might be able to infer which are power by their wires being thicker or multiple, but not always.

Comment: @rdtsc Thank you for your comment - I have determined experimentally via an oscilloscope and a power supply that the ratio between the coils is 1:1. On the PCB I removed it from, it was also clear that there was only a primary and secondary coil.

Comment: You may be able to remove the ferrite core halves by removing the yellow tape (mylar transformer tape) if the core hasn't been glued together. Once the ferrite halves have been removed, look for the gap on the center leg of the core.

Comment: It seems you want the transformer to be gapped, because of an assumption that being gapped will lead to certain performance characteristics.  So what actually matters is the performance of the transformer in terms of saturation, inductance, rated current, leakage capacitance, etc. (not whether or not its gapped).  Things like inductance, saturation, and capacitance can be measured.

Comment: @user4574 Mostly I am interested in what topology this transformer is best suited for. I guess I could use the mentioned performance characteristics instead of physical geometry to determine this.

Comment: It doesnt matter if gapped or not as @user4574 explains.

Answer (score 2):

If you knew the exact core material and the winding/pinout then it might be possible. But you probably know almost nothing about it. So it's almost impossible to know if the transformer has an air gap or not without a datasheet or dismantling it. It looks like a Chinese custom-made transformer, so you'd better expect to find nothing.

@qrk has suggested removing the core halves. I suggest the same thing. However, the excessive lacquer is probably holding the core halves together quite strong, so it'll not be easy to remove them. A heat gun may help. Be careful, because you'll probably damage the insulation of the wires while applying the heat towards the cores. And also there's a risk of breaking the bobbin. Although it looks like made from phenolic which has a maximum temperature endurance of higher than 500 degrees Celcius, care should be taken.

Comment: This seems like a good idea. I'll work on this tomorrow.

Answer (score 2):

More important is how much does L change with DC current.  Measure the 10% 25% and 40% L drop currents.

If the LCR meter does not support DC current, create something to do the same or design your own sweep circuit.

I used a power Darlington current source with a variable 5V supply and series LC swept the resonant frequency with a low impedance source.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For investigation I would find a two windings.

Measure their inductances with RLC meter, time constant method, capacitor oscillation freq., whatever.

From inductances find a turn ratio (remember the inductances are squared).

Now, if you apply AC voltage (sine or square) to one winding in non-gapped core the voltage one second winding should be "exactly" turn ratio times more (some drop will be presented due to windings resistances).

In gapped core this voltage will be much less (depends on gap length).